# What is the equivalent of php includes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

What would be the best approach in creating a top navigation and footer for an Angular app that can be reused across multiple views? I'm thinking a `directive` is the way to go. What I'd like to accomplish would be the comparable to wp_header(); and wp_footer(); in wordpress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach is SPA (Single Page Application) using `ngView` along with routings. The second less elegante option is to use `ngInclude` this can be used like a "template"/reusable section within the pages.

You can find really good examples here in Angular Documentation site:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude